# .htaccess redirect: add www for only one specific URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect http://example.com/sitemap.xml to http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml.

So I added a rewrite rule in .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /sitemap.xml http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

But I get an error: "This webpage has a redirect loop" (actually make sense)

If I change it to

```
Redirect 301 http://example.com/sitemap.xml http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

It doesn't work at all. Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess problems with redirect for no www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202057/htaccess-problems-with-redirect-for-no-www)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `mod_rewrite` rules for this to first check if URL doesn't already have `www`.

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(sitemap\.xml)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```